# Making file input filed work on Android nativescript vue webview

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-vue

## Complete Solution for VUE on [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=XBvmse&v=5).

---

I'm creating an app with NativeScript Vue and I am using webview as a main component. In the loaded website there is a file input field to capture camera input.

It works great on iOS devices but on Android, the input field doesn't work.

Has anyone know a solution to make file input fields to work on Android webview?

I use tns-android version: 6.1.1

## **Update 1**

#### Which platform am I using?

- Android
- 10.0
- emulator. Pixel 3a

#### More info about the stack:

- CLI: 6.1.2
- nodejs: v10.16.0
- tns-core-modules: tns-core-modules@6.1.1
- Runtime(s):

  > "tns-android": {
  >         "version": "6.1.1"
  >       },
  >       "tns-ios": {
  >         "version": "6.1.0"
  >       }
- Plugin(s):

> "dependencies": {
>
> ```
> "@nota/nativescript-webview-ext": "^5.4.1",
>
> "@nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus": "^2.2.6",
>
> "axios": "^0.19.0",
>
> "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
>
> "nativescript-camera": "^4.5.0",
>
> "nativescript-geolocation": "^5.1.0",
>
> "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^9.1.1",
>
> "nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.6",
>
> "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^7.0.2",
>
> "nativescript-vue": "~2.4.0",
>
> "net": "^1.0.2",
>
> "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
>
> "tns-core-modules": "~6.1.0",
>
> "vuex": "^3.1.1"
> ```
>
> },
>
> "devDependencies": {
>
> ```
> "@babel/core": "~7.1.0",
>
> "@babel/preset-env": "~7.1.0",
>
> "babel-loader": "~8.0.0",
>
> "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.2.0",
>
> "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "~2.4.0",
>
> "node-sass": "^4.7.1",
>
> "vue-loader": "~15.4.0"
> ```
>
> },

In my Vue file (where the webview is loaded), I load the website like this:

```
<webview    @loaded="onWebViewLoaded" :src="webViewSrc"
                     :builtInZoomControls="false"
                     :displayZoomControls="false"
                     :debugMode="true"
/>
```

And then in the **onWebViewLoaded** I try doing this:
let myWebChromeClientClass = androidVm.webkit.WebChromeClient.extend({

```
                    onShowFileChooser: function (WebView, ValueCallback, FileChooserParams) {
                        // FileChooserParams.createIntent()

                        camera.takePicture() // Using nativescript-camera
                            .then(function (imageAsset) {
                                console.log("Result is an image asset instance");
                                var image = new Image();
                                image.src = imageAsset;
                                console.log(image)
                            }).catch(function (err) {
                            console.log("Error -> " + err.message);
                        });

                        return false
                    }
                });
                let myWebChromeClient = new myWebChromeClientClass();
                webView.android.setWebChromeClient(myWebChromeClient);
```

Currently, I'm struggling to make the nativescript-camera behave after taking the picture (always returns 'canceled') but I know there is a way to show the native file input selection using FileChooserParams but I can't make this work either as the closest solution that I've found on the net is for Java and not really sure how to transform this to Javascript / Vue.

Any more ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to extend `android.webkit.WebChromeClient` and assign the same on `nativeView`.

You will have to implement [onShowFileChooser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient#onShowFileChooser(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Candroid.net.Uri%5B%5D%3E,%20android.webkit.WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams)) method, handle the selection of file using Intent or something.

Comment: Thanks but do you have any ideas on how to do this on NativeScript (Vue)?

Comment: You may refer the [related forum thread here](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/how-to-use-open-file-from-device-and-upload-using-webview/4656) which showcases a minimal example.

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying a lot of things and been scanning through a lot of sources to find a solution but without a luck.

Take a look at my updated original post. 
Do you have any ideas how can I solve my problem?

Comment: Just call the value callback with file uri, `ValueCallback.onReceiveValue(android.net.Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(imageAsset.android)));`

Comment: using your solution I get this error: "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri cannot be cast to android.net.Uri[]".

Comment: ``'Error -> Expect integer value as a second argument.'``

Where exactly is the integer value expected and what should it be? (Sorry, I'm not familiar with the Java part here at all).

Comment: Sorry, it was untested. I ran the code and made sure the array is created properly. `const uris = Array.create(android.net.Uri, 1); uris[0] = android.net.Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(imageAsset.android)); ValueCallback.onReceiveValue(uris);`

Comment: long time but it finally works! Thanks a lot for this solution! In my particular setup, I get ``java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate showFileChooser result`` if I return false in showFileChooser. If I return ``true``, it works, but the camera opens only for 1 time.
Do you know what is the correct way to handle this so it would work every time properly?

Comment: Without seeing your complete code, I'm not sure what that could be. Share the Playground sample.

Comment: The code is similar to the code in my initial post. I've also created a playground project: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=XBvmse
(haven't tested it on Android as I only have a virtual device, but it should give you an idea as this is basically what I'm using)

Comment: I don't see any issue as such when returning `true`, it worked on my Android 8.1. But a minor issue here is that, loading event will be triggered every time when you return to app from camera and it will reset the client once again. In order to avoid that, I have added a check and it works on my end. [Here is updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=XBvmse&v=3). Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Your example works great if you take a picture and confirm it, then you can click the input field again. But if you take a picture, but don't confirm and click cancel, then you no longer can click on the input file field. Do you experience this issue at your end?

Comment: You are not calling value callback when there is an error, you should with empty array - [Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=XBvmse&v=4)

Comment: Yup! That was it! Thanks a bunch!